# Removing an image in a wx python panel using a button

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm new to python/wxpython.
I have a wxpython frame which is split vertically - displaying 2 panels. On the left panel i have a display window, which displays an image by allowing the user to  browse for a file by clicking on a button added onto the right panel. The loading of the image works fine, however i want to be able to remove the image by clicking on a created 'remove' button (right panel) so the user can choose to load another image. I have tried to look up GetFocusedItem() and selecting the panel on the left, but it returns an error "'panelLeft' object has no attribute 'GetFocusedItem'"

Any suggestion how to best tackle this?

Many thanks,
HP

Please find the code below.
The image that i am using is a 3-D rendered image which is interactive and can be moved around and rotated, however i want to be able click the event button on the right panel namely 'crops image' or 'remove'[To give you an idea of the display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SIX2.jpg).

The 'crop image' button has a attached draw rectangle function which i want to use to crop the image and 'Remove' button to remove the loaded image,but i cant seem to get over the hurdle of keeping the rotating 3-D image on the left panel (using the mouse) and only locking it when i want to crop or remove. Hope that makes sense.

Any suggestions?

```
import wx
import vtk
from vtk.wx.wxVTKRenderWindowInteractor import wxVTKRenderWindowInteractor
from wx.lib.dialogs import openFileDialog
from wx.lib import eventwatcher


class p1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.widget = wxVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self, -1)
        self.widget.Enable(1)
        self.widget.AddObserver("ExitEvent", lambda o,e,f=self: f.Close())
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.widget, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Layout()
        self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.filename=""
        self.isploted = False


    def renderthis(self):

            self.widget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)


            openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self,"Open STL file", "", self.filename,"*.stl",wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)

            if openFileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
                return 
            self.filename = openFileDialog.GetPath()

            reader = vtk.vtk.vtkSTLReader()
            reader.SetFileName(self.filename)

            normals = vtk.vtkPolyDataNormals()
            normals.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
            normals.Update()


            mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
            mapper.SetInputConnection(normals.GetOutputPort())

            if self.isploted:
                actor = self.ren.GetActors().GetlastActor()
                self.ren.RemoveActor(actor)
            actor = vtk.vtkActor()
            actor.SetMapper(mapper)

            self.ren.AddActor(actor)             

            if not self.isploted:
                axes = vtk.vtkAxesActor()
                self.marker = vtk.vtkOrientationMarkerWidget()
                self.marker.SetInteractor( self.widget._Iren )
                self.marker.SetOrientationMarker( axes )
                self.marker.SetViewport(0.75,0,1,0.25)
                self.marker.SetEnabled(1)

            self.ren.ResetCamera()
            self.ren.ResetCameraClippingRange()
            cam = self.ren.GetActiveCamera()
            cam.Elevation(10)
            cam.Azimuth(70)
            self.isploted = True
            self.ren.Render()

class VTKFrame(wx.Frame):
    pos1 = None 
    pos2 = None
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title=title,size=(1050,600), style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|
                  wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)


        self.sp = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        self.p1 = p1(self.sp)
        self.p2 = wx.Panel(self.sp,style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        self.sp.SplitVertically(self.p1,self.p2,870)

        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.statusbar.SetStatusText("Click to load a STL file")

        self.plotbut = wx.Button(self.p2,-1,"Browse for STL file ", size=(120,20),pos=(10,10))
        self.plotbut.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.plot)

        self.Box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.button1 = wx.Button(self.p2,2, "Crop image ", size=(120,20),pos=(10,35))
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnPaint)

        self.button2 = wx.Button(self.p2,3, "Remove", size=(120,20),pos=(10,60))
        self.button2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton2)


        self.button3 = wx.Button(self.p2,4,"Close", size=(120,20),pos=(10,85))
        self.button3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton3)


    def plot(self,event):
        self.p1.renderthis()
        self.SetTitle("STL File Viewer: "+self.p1.filename)



    def OnButton2(self,event):
        wx.EmptyImage(self.p1)


    def OnButton3(self,event):
        self.Close()


    def OnPaint(self,event):
        if self.pos1 is None or self.pos2 is None: return 

        dc = wx.PaintDC(self.p1)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('White', 1))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.Color(0,0,0), wx.RED))

        dc.DrawRectangle(self.pos1.x, self.pos1.y, self.pos2.x - self.pos1.x, self.pos2.y -self.pos2.y)

        def PrintPos(self,position):
            return str(position.x) + "" + str(position.y)        



app = wx.App(redirect=False)
frame = VTKFrame(None,"STL File Viewer")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a handle on the `wx.StaticBitmap` widget that you're using to display the image. You can just hide that widget or set it to an `wx.EmptyImage`.

I wrote a simple image viewer application that you can check out. It might help you figure this out:

```
import os
import wx

class PhotoCtrl(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, title='Photo Control')

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self.frame)

        self.PhotoMaxSize = 240

        self.createWidgets()
        self.frame.Show()

    def createWidgets(self):
        instructions = 'Browse for an image'
        img = wx.EmptyImage(240,240)
        self.imageCtrl = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 
                                         wx.BitmapFromImage(img))

        instructLbl = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label=instructions)
        self.photoTxt = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, size=(200,-1))
        browseBtn = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Browse')
        browseBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onBrowse)

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.mainSizer.Add(wx.StaticLine(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY),
                           0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(instructLbl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.imageCtrl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.photoTxt, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(browseBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)        
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.panel.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        self.mainSizer.Fit(self.frame)

        self.panel.Layout()

    def onBrowse(self, event):
        """ 
        Browse for file
        """
        wildcard = "JPEG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg"
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, "Choose a file",
                               wildcard=wildcard,
                               style=wx.OPEN)
        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.photoTxt.SetValue(dialog.GetPath())
        dialog.Destroy() 
        self.onView()

    def onView(self):
        filepath = self.photoTxt.GetValue()
        img = wx.Image(filepath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        # scale the image, preserving the aspect ratio
        W = img.GetWidth()
        H = img.GetHeight()
        if W > H:
            NewW = self.PhotoMaxSize
            NewH = self.PhotoMaxSize * H / W
        else:
            NewH = self.PhotoMaxSize
            NewW = self.PhotoMaxSize * W / H
        img = img.Scale(NewW,NewH)

        self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
        self.panel.Refresh()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = PhotoCtrl()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You can read more about it [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/26/creating-a-simple-photo-viewer-with-wxpython/)